# how to force the browser to hide an element even if it is shown again after few seconds

Tags: javascript, visibility, opacity

Look at the following html code of the web page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><script>
function hide()
{
 var e = document.getElementById('test');
 e.style.transition = 'visibility 0s,opacity 0s';
 e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 e.style.opacity = '0';
 e.style.transition = 'visibility 5s,opacity 5s';
 show();
}
function show()
{
 var e = document.getElementById('test');
 e.style.visibility = 'visible';
 e.style.opacity = '1';
}
</script></head><body>
<div id="test">Test</div>
<button type="button" onclick="hide()">go!</button>
</body></html>
```

If you open this html file in any standard browser (I tested in on Mozilla Firefox and Opera, under Windows 7) and click the button, nothing will happen (the text 'Test' will not vanish!).

I'm guessing that this is a matter of a kind of 'intelligence' of the browser. So, my question is: is it possible (for the above html code) to force the browser to hide the element?

Comment: After your update the question is completely different: now your code is executing hide and show immediately after each other leaving no time for anything to be actually hidden, as you immediately tell it to show.

Comment: But I've changed the transition - why it does not take 5 seconds to show the hidden element?

Comment: You should not change the same style value twice at the same moment: the first value will then not be processed. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not perform multiple changes to the same style property at once (`transition` and `opacity` in your case), as only the last values assigned to those properties will actually get an effect. The other value(s) are not processed by the browser -- that only happens when you give control back to the browser.

So only set the opacity to one value, the transition to one value, and then give control back.

Use `setTimeout` for this: it gives control back to the browser who will call you back when a certain time has elapsed.

```js
function hide() { 
    var e = document.getElementById('test'); 
    e.style.transition = 'opacity 0s'; 
    e.style.opacity = 0; 
    setTimeout(showSlowly, 100); // This gives the browser time to perform the hiding action
} 

function showSlowly() {
    var e = document.getElementById('test'); 
    e.style.transition = 'opacity 2s'; 
    e.style.opacity = 1; 
}
```

```html
<div id="test">Test</div>
<button type="button" onclick="hide()">go!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works! So, the point is that the second change of transition has to be placed in a different function which is called after some (not to short) delay. Thank you so much - this is exactly what I was looking for!!! (It also works when transition changes simultaneously opacity and visibility.)

Answer (score 0):

Read about Mutation Observers and how to react to specific DOM changes elegantly.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Basically, you instantiate the MutationObserver object, setup the listeners and define the code to be run when a certain change in DOM appears.